# Открывать диплинки только в самом приложении и запретить предлагать открыть в браузере

Tags: android, deeplink

У некоторых пользователей диплинки не предлагается открывать в моем приложении, а пытается в браузере (а веб версии соответственно нет). В связи с этим 2 вопроса:

1. Как сделать чтобы устройство не предлагало открывать диплинки в браузере, а только в приложении?
2. ... либо если приложение не установлено - то чтобы предлагало его скачать (если это возможно)?

Answer (score 0):

По первому пункту: вы можете использовать [custom scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2448531/1979756), которую будет понимать только ваше приложение.

По второму: используйте сервисы, которые позволяют настроить сценарий открытия ссылки – вести на сайт или в Play Store, если приложение не установлено.

Популярные сервисы: [Branch.io](https://branch.io/what-is-applink/), [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/products/dynamic-links/), [AppsFlyer OneLink](https://www.appsflyer.com/products/customer-experience-deep-linking/)